# White rectangle artifact appearing while UIPopoverPresentationController animates growth after increasing the preferredContentSize

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, uikit

I am using a `UIPopoverPresentationViewController` to present a `UIViewController` modally in a popover. According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621476-preferredcontentsize), updating the `preferredContentSize` property on `UIViewController` while it is being presented in a popover will animate the size change.

While the size change is working, certain values for `preferredContentSize` will cause this strange white rectangle artifact during the animation. Other than the this weird white rectangle appearing, the animation works perfectly.

[image: White Rectangle Artifact]

This is the code that I am using to present my popover. In this instance, a `preferredContentSize` set to `CGSize(width: 200, height: 100)` is causing the artifact to appear. If I use a `CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)` everything works perfectly with no artifacting.

```
@objc private func presentPopover() {
    let vc = UIViewController()

    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 50)

    guard let popVC = vc.presentationController as? UIPopoverPresentationController else {
        fatalError("View Controller must have a Popover Presentation Controller")
    }

    popVC.sourceView = self.view
    popVC.sourceRect = self.label.frame
    popVC.delegate = self
    popVC.permittedArrowDirections = .up

    self.present(vc, animated: true)

    // very short delay to allow popover growth to animate
    // without delay, layout happens so quickly that no animation is visible
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.15, repeats: false) { (timer) in
        vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: self.popoverHeight)
    }
}

func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
}

func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController, traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
}
```

There appears to be some relationship between the artifact appearing and the `preferredContentSize`, but I just can't decipher what that relationship is.

I have tried scheduling the `Timer` later than 0.1 seconds (e.g. 1 second, 5 seconds) in the future thinking that there may be some layout race condition but that did not solve the issue. With no `Timer`, the popover automatically appears at the final `preferredContentSize` without animating. I assume this happens because layout happens so quickly. Using another delay construct such as `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline:execute:)` also causes the white rectangle artifact to appear.

Comment: Hey, how did you fix this issue?